# First function triggers second

Tags: javascript

I am terrible at javascript, how do I get function 1 (fade) to call / trigger function 2 (continuity) on completion of the volume fade as set out in the first. I have found answers in JQuery how would I do this in pure JS.

Function 1:

```
 function fade(){
        "use strict";
        var timepiece,
        soundwaves = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
        if (soundwaves.volume > 0) {
        soundwaves.volume -= 0.005;
        timepiece = setTimeout(fade, 80);
            }
        }
```

Function 2:

```
        <!-- Continuity: (Javascript) -->

        function continuity(){
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll("main")[0];
        elements.style.transition = "opacity 3s linear 0s";
        elements.style.opacity = 1.0;

        var audiofade,
        audio = document.getElementById("ambience");
        if (audio.volume < 1.0) {
        audio.volume += 0.005;
        audiofade = setTimeout(sync, 80);
        }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

simply call second in the `else` block

```
function fade()
{
    "use strict";
    var timepiece,
    soundwaves = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    if (soundwaves.volume > 0) 
    {
        soundwaves.volume -= 0.005;
        timepiece = setTimeout(fade, 80);
    }
    else
    {
       continuity();
    }
}
```